# How to Update a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

[image]I am trying to update my database table **ExpenseManagement**. But it is not Updated.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Configuration;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Data;


public partial class UserProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            txtUserId.Text = Request.Cookies["txtUserName"].Value;

            string con_string = @"data Source= 10.10.10.5; initial catalog= test; user= xx; password= xxxxxxxxx;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName, Password, EmailId, MobileNumber from ExpenseManagement where UserId ='"+txtUserId.Text+"'", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtUserId.Text);

            con.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);

            txtFirstName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].ToString();

            txtLastName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastName"].ToString();

            txtPassword.Text= dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();

            txtEmailId.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EmailId"].ToString();

            txtMobileNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MobileNumber"].ToString();

            con.Close();

            txtUserId.Enabled = false;

            txtFirstName.Enabled=false;

            txtLastName.Enabled=false;

            txtPassword.Enabled = false;

            txtEmailId.Enabled = false;

            txtMobileNumber.Enabled = false;

            btnUpdate.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtUserId.Enabled = true;

        txtUserId.ReadOnly = true;

        txtFirstName.Enabled = true;

        txtLastName.Enabled = true;

        txtPassword.Enabled = true;

        txtMobileNumber.Enabled = true;

        txtEmailId.Enabled = true;

        btnUpdate.Visible = true;

        btnEdit.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string con_string = @"data Source= 10.10.10.5; initial catalog= test; user= xx; password= xxxxxxxxx;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);

        string qryUpdate = "Update ExpenseManagement set FirstName= @FirstName, LastName=@LastName, Password=@Password, EmailId=@EmailId,MobileNumber=@MobileNumber where UserId= @UserId";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryUpdate, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtUserId.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", txtEmailId.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", txtMobileNumber.Text);

        con.Open();

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            btnEdit.Visible = true;
        }

        con.Close();   
    }
}
```

I have next database fields:

```
UserId, FirstName, LastName, Password, EmailId, MobileNumber.
```

Comment: @Nimesh Getting No error.

Comment: Use connection string as
`Server=10.10.10.5;User id=sa;password=multiverse@1;Initial Catalog=test`

Comment: is ` UserId= @UserId` exits in databse? what you are passing in @userid?

Comment: check `txtUserId.Text` is should not containing space after or before the value.

Comment: Place `BreakPoint` at `if (Page.IsValid)` and check if control is going inside.

Comment: Control is going in it bcoz i have keep  btnEdit.Visible = true; code in it. It's working.

Comment: try to update a single field without parameter. for example `"Update ExpenseManagement set FirstName='" + txtFirstName.Text + "' where UserId='" + txtUserId.Text + "'"` and execute it. still it fail then try to execute that query directly in SSMS.

Comment: @steve  not numeric, it's varchar

Comment: @steve tried your code- not working

Comment: As I can see from your code, there are 3 possibilities of errors. 1) The connection string is wrong (`;User ID=xx;`), 2) The Page is not valid, 3) The UserID parameters cannot find any string (why use a varchar?)

Comment: @AzharShahid Have u changed your connection string???

Comment: Where are you calling `Page.Validate();`?

Comment: @Steve- my userId's are A1001, A1002, so on... Which datatype should I use ?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari- connection string is fine, I am inserting with same connection string.

Comment: You've written 'not working' twice. Never say not working. Always explain in what way. Is it not working because a record you expect to be updated is not updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) check on the Page_Load event.

In ASP.NET, when you raise an event on a server side control, the Page_Load event is always executed before the code in the control event.

In your case, your user changes the textboxes, then presses the Update button. This raises the `Page_Load` event followed by the  `btnUpdate_Click` event. Without a check on the property `IsPostBack`, the Page_Load event reloads the textboxes from the database with the original values effectively destroying the data typed by the user, then the button event code is called. But at this point the values in the textboxes are the original ones, so your code runs correctly, but doesn't change anything.

Change the Page_Load event adding

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
        txtUserId.Text = Request.Cookies["txtUserName"].Value;
        string con_string = @"data Source= 10.10.10.5; initial catalog= test; user= xx; password= xxxxxxxxx;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select FirstName, LastName, Password, 
                                          EmailId, MobileNumber 
                                          from ExpenseManagement 
                                          where UserId =@usedId", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtUserId.Text);
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        ......
        btnUpdate.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend for the command to be more readable to user @ instead of concatenating strings with "+" sign as below:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string con_string = @"data Source= 10.10.10.5;initial catalog= test; user= xx; password= xxxxxxxxx;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
            string qryUpdate = @"Update ExpenseManagement 
                                 set FirstName= @FirstName, 
                                    LastName=@LastName, 
                                    Password=@Password,
                                    EmailId=@EmailId,
                                    MobileNumber=@MobileNumber 
                                    where UserId= @UserId";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryUpdate, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", txtEmailId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber", txtMobileNumber.Text);
            con.Open();

            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                btnEdit.Visible = true;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Also I agree with RezaRahmati to convert the userId and other parameters to correct types you have defined in your database, table columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", txtUserId.Text);` because it add a parameter of type `string` (because txtUserId.Text is string) instead of `int` or `long`, so change it to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", int.parse(txtUserId.Text));` or use `cmd.Parameters.Add()` which takes `type` as argument.

Comment: my userId's are A1001, A1002, so on.. It's not working.

Comment: Showing exception- "input string is not in correct format"

Comment: Can you run a `sql profiler` and tell us what is the statement that is running in sql server?